# Connecting Huawei R207 on Ubuntu 14 via USB

Tags: usb, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

Has anyone tried to connect the Huawei R207 (Broadband device) via USB to Ubuntu 14?

1. When I connect the device to USB, Ubuntu recognizes it as a hard drive.
2. I eject the drive using right click.
3. It is not recognized as a USB broadband device.

My question is: how can I have Ubuntu 14 recognize this Huawei R207 as a USB broadband device?

Comment: Please elaborate the question. Otherwise it will be closed

Comment: elaborated the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use `usb-modeswitch`](/q/272745)

Comment: R207 is still not recognized by Ubuntu 15 even after applying whats in the article of usb-modeswitch

Comment: Turned out that this model should be recognized as a remote NDIS or a network card - so not worth spending more time on it